# proc cluster in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm have the following codes to classify datas:

```
proc cluster data = Sasuser.Live;
method=ave outtree= Sasuser.LiveClassify;
var GDP Income Consumption Employment Education Health Life
id Region;
run;
```

with the data Sasuse.Live as shown:

[image]

I then get the following error:

```
1    proc cluster data = Sasuser.Live;
2    method=ave outtree= Sasuser.LiveClassify;
     ------
     180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
3    var GDP Income Consumption Employment Education Health Life
4    id Region;
ERROR: Variable ID not found.
ERROR: Variable Region in list does not match type prescribed for this list.
5    run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.DATA1 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0
         observations and 0 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE CLUSTER used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: Remove the ; at the end of line 1

Comment: It dosen't work

Comment: Need proof show your work.

Comment: Remove the ; at the end of line 1 **AND** add ; at the end of line 3.

Comment: Please don't post data as an image.